# If I use multiple middleware in gin what is the order in which they are executed

Tags: go, go-gin

If I use multiple middleware and I want to use output of `mw1` in `mw2` using `ctx.Set` and `ctx.Get` is there any defined order in which middleware are executed?

```golang
func main() {
    // Creates a router without any middleware by default
    r := gin.New()

    // Global middleware
    // Logger middleware will write the logs to gin.DefaultWriter even you set with GIN_MODE=release.
    // By default gin.DefaultWriter = os.Stdout
    r.Use(mw1)

    // Recovery middleware recovers from any panics and writes a 500 if there was one.
    r.Use(mw2)

    // Per route middleware, you can add as many as you desire.
    r.GET("/benchmark", MyBenchLogger(), benchEndpoint)
}
```

For instance in above sniped is `mw1` called first, or `mw2` is? And is there a guarantee on their ordering?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are executed in the order they are added to the router. That's why it is usually referred as *middleware chain*.

As you can see from the signature of functions that take middleware args, as  `Use`, `Group`, etc. middlewares have type `HandlerFunc` and they are added to the `HandlersChain`, which is defined as:

```
type HandlersChain []HandlerFunc
```

So you can assume that context values set in a previous middleware will be available in the subsequent ones:

```
func main() {
    r := gin.New()
    r.Use(func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Set("key", "foo")
    })
    
    r.Use(func(c *gin.Context) {
        fmt.Println(c.MustGet("key").(string)) // foo 
    })
}
```